# How to display data from list in application page using SPGridview

Tags: list, application-pages, spgridview

I have created an application page which displays data from the list.
I am able to see dropdown and labels server control./
but when i try to bind the list data to the SPgrid view , nothin gets rendered.
below is the application page code :
ASPX:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="" Inherits="" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" </SharePoint:SPGridView>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >

</asp:Content>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    try
    {
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))

         using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
         {

              //Creation of data table
              table = new DataTable();
              table.Columns.Add("INDEX", typeof(Int32));
              table.Columns.Add("ENTRY", typeof(string));

                                      string dayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                                      SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["Cafeteria"];

              //Query to get the Entress items with Price big
              SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
              query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Day' /><Value Type='Choice'>" + dayOfWeek + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Type' /><Value Type='Choice'>etr</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='PrBig' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
              SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(query);

              GetDetails(web, coll);



              gvCafe.DataSource = table;
              gvCafe.DataBind();

private void GetDetails(SPWeb web, SPListItemCollection coll)
{
    if (coll.Count > 0)
    {
         row = table.Rows.Add();
         //SetDefaultImage(web);
         row["INDEX"] = 1;
         row["ENTRY"] = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(coll[0].Web.Url, coll[0].Url);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have visual webpart where it works but when i try to work with application page it doesnt throw me any error but it doesnt render the spfridview ":(

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code and the error you are receiving.

Comment: i dnt get any error as such.code runs but the grid isnt rendering

Comment: @Nikhil what Kit ment was please add more context to the question, such as code that works, code that throws the error, the error in question. As Q is now, it is not answerable and will be deleted. Also a comment like "send me some links" isnt likely to get much love from our audience: do your homework, give us something to work with, and eventually we can help you. Thanx!

Comment: The code sample is incomplete? Looks like one and a half functions. I don't see where you populate `table` at all.

Comment: SPGridview works for me if i use SPDataSource as it's datasource and bind it.